# Script to display only first h2 tag in a div after filters are applied each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Please see this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/as0tpwmt/

I am trying to create some **script** that will only display the first **h2** tag in each div with the class "resultHolder" even after each time a user applies a different filter.  For example, select March and only the color Red.  Instead of "**RED**" showing up twice in the results, the script will only allow it to display the first time.

```
<div class="resultHolder">
  <div class="rResult red jan feb mar ">
    <h2>RED</h2>
    <h3>SUPER RED</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>January</li>
      <li>February</li>
      <li>March</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">CTA</a>
  </div>
  <div class="rResult red mar apr may">
    <h2>RED</h2>
    <h3>DARK RED</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>March</li>
      <li>April</li>
      <li>May</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">CTA</a>
  </div>


  <div class="rResult red may jun jul">
    <h2>RED</h2>
    <h3>LIGHT RED</h3>
    <ul>
       <li>May</li>
      <li>June</li>
      <li>July</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">CTA</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify a little as to what are you trying to achieve from your code, or what particular thing should happen on click of any particular color say RED, GREEN or blah ? Please clarify little more!

Comment: Rather than pasting a large chunk of html, it would be easier to answer if you used a more manageable amount of code. It looks like there's a lot here that you could trim out to make it easier to understand your question.

Comment: For example, if you were to select "March" from the drop down list and then only select Red.  Instead of RED displaying twice, over both SUPER RED and DARK RED in the results, I would like RED to just display the first time.

Answer (score 0):

In your `window.filter() function` do the following changes:

```
window.filter = function() {
  var month = $('#month-select').val();
  if (month == null || month == "")
    $('.rResult').show(); //show all
  else {
    $('.rResult').hide(); // hide all 
    $('.rResult.' + month).show(); //filter by month
   var redCount = 0;
   var greenCount = 0;
   $('.' + month).find('h2').each(function(){ 
    if($(this).html().toLowerCase() == "red") { 
        redCount++;
      }
     if($(this).html().toLowerCase() == "green") { 
        greenCount++;
      }
   });

   if(redCount > 1)
   {
        $('.resultHolder').find('.red.' + month + ':not(:first) h2').hide();
        $('.resultHolder').find('.red.' + month + ':first').find('h2').show();
   }
   if(greenCount > 1)
   {
        $('.resultHolder').find('.green.' + month + ':not(:first) h2').hide();
        $('.resultHolder').find('.green.' + month + ':first').find('h2').show();
   }
  }

  var strColorFilter = [];
  var checkedItems = $(".checkColor:not(:checked)").map(function(i, o) {
return "." + o.id;
  }).get();
  //filter by color
  if (checkedItems.length == 0) return;
  strColorFilter.push(".rResult:visible"); //take on visible after month filter
  strColorFilter.push(checkedItems);
  $(strColorFilter.join("")).hide();

}
```

This will give you the desired result. On selecting 'red', `h2` containing 'red' will be shown once only. Similarly for 'green' also.

Here is the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as0tpwmt/3/) for the same. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Alorika for the help but that isn't the desired result.  I'm trying to get the script to only display both versions of the red color but only display the red h2 tag once.  the desired result would be RED: SUPER RED: list, DARK RED:list. if March and Red were selected as filters.

Comment: The objective here is to only display the main category color once but still display the variations of that color below it - if the filters applied.

Comment: Updated the code. Please check if it suits your requirement and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I got your desired output, make some changes in HTML and Javascript as per following, its working:

HTML:

```
<select name="month-select" id="month-select">
    <option value="" id="select">Select a Month</option>
    <option value="jan" id="jan" name="jan">January</option>
    <option value="feb" id="feb" name="feb">February</option>
    <option value="mar" id="mar" name="mar">March</option>
    <option value="apr" id="apr" name="apr">April</option>
    <option value="may" id="may" name="may">May</option>
    <option value="jun" id="jun" name="jun">June</option>
    <option value="jul" id="jul" name="jul">July</option>
    <option value="aug" id="aug" name="aug">August</option>
    <option value="sep" id="sep" name="sep">September</option>
    <option value="oct" id="oct" name="oct">October</option>
    <option value="nov" id="nov" name="nov">November</option>
    <option value="dec" id="dec" name="dec">December</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" value="red" id="red" onclick="Color.filterByColor(this);" checked="checked" class="checkColor checkbox checkboxColor">
<label for="Color">red</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="green" id="green" onclick="Color.filterByColor(this);" checked="checked" class="checkColor checkbox checkboxColor">
<label for="Color">green</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="blue" id="blue" onclick="Color.filterByColor(this);" checked="checked" class="checkColor checkbox checkboxColor">
<label for="Color">blue</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="selectall" id="selectall" onclick="Color.filterByColorSelectAll();" checked="checked" class="checkbox checkboxColor">
<label for="Color">select all colors</label>

<div class="resultsNumberShowing">
    <b>Showing
    <span class="textForALL">ALL ( </span><span id="activeresults" class="NumberShowing"></span> of <span id="totalresults" class="NumberTotal"></span><span class="textForALL">) </span></b> Results
</div>

<div id="fulllist">
    <div class="resultHolder">
        <h2>RED</h2>
        <div class="rResult red jan feb mar ">
            <h3>SUPER RED</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>January</li>
                <li>February</li>
                <li>March</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#">CTA</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rResult red mar apr may">
            <h3>DARK RED</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>March</li>
                <li>April</li>
                <li>May</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#">CTA</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rResult red may jun jul">
            <h3>LIGHT RED</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>May</li>
                <li>June</li>
                <li>July</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#">CTA</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="resultHolder">
        <div class="rResult green jan feb mar">
            <h3>SUPER GREEN</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>January</li>
                <li>February</li>
                <li>March</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#">CTA</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rResult green mar apr may">
            <h3>Light GREEN</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>March</li>
                <li>April</li>
                <li>May</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#">CTA</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rResult green may jun jul">
            <h3>DARK GREEN</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>February</li>
                <li>March</li>
                <li>April</li>
            </ul>
        <a href="#">CTA</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rResult green mar apr may">
            <ul>
                <li>March</li>
                <li>April</li>
                <li>May</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#">CTA</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#month-select').on('change', function() {
    window.filter();
    updateCounter();
});
window.Color = {
    filterByColor: function() {
        window.filter();
        updateCounter();
    },
    filterByColorSelectAll: function() {
        if ($("#selectall").is(":checked")){
            $(".checkColor").prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $(".checkColor").removeProp("checked");
            window.filter();
            updateCounter();
        }
    }
}
window.filter = function() {
    var month = $('#month-select').val();
    if (month == null || month == "") {
        $('.rResult').show(); //show all
    } else {
        $('.rResult').hide(); // hide all 
        $('.rResult.' + month).show(); //filter by month
    }

    var strColorFilter = [];
    var checkedItems = $(".checkColor:not(:checked)").map(function(i, o) {
        return "." + o.id;
    }).get();
    var tempItems = $(".checkColor:checked").map(function(i, o) {
        var newTemp = o.id;
        newTemp = newTemp.toUpperCase();
        return newTemp;
    }).get();
    $("#fulllist .resultHolder h2").text(tempItems);

    //filter by color
    if (checkedItems.length == 0) {
         return;
    }
    strColorFilter.push(".rResult:visible"); //take on visible after month filter
    strColorFilter.push(checkedItems);
    $(strColorFilter.join("")).hide();
}

$(document.body).append($("<div>"));
var n = $(".rResult").length;
$( "#totalresults" ).text( n);

$(document.body).append($("<div>"));
var x = $(".rResult").filter(":visible").length;
$("#activeresults").text(x);

function updateCounter(){
    var totalColors = 0;
    totalColors = $(".rResult:visible").length;
    if(totalColors == -1){
        totalColors = 0;
    }
    $("#activeresults").html(totalColors);
}
```